# Unable to use "join data" to combine multiple datasets into one using Azure Machine Learning Studio Designer

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-machine-learning-service

How can I combine mutiple datasets into one using Azure Machine Learning Studio?

(The following graph doesn't work)
[image]

Same question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/666021/unable-to-use-34join-data34-to-combine-multiple-da.html

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/join-data#how-to-configure-join-data), The Join Data module does not support a right outer join, so if you want to ensure that rows from a particular dataset are included in the output, that dataset must be on the lefthand input.

[image]

For more information follow this link - [How to configure Join Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/join-data#how-to-configure-join-data)

Comment: There is no "Right Outer Join" Option. The problem is: I could successfully run the first "Join Data", but the second "Join Data" failed. The second "Join Data" is unable to combine the first "Join Data" Dataset with another dataset named "Aruoba-Diebold-Scotti Business Conditions Index".